How to fix column with numeric values that is taken as a string field because of empty strings in Pandas dataframe?
I have a df with some columns that are supposed to be numeric fields. However, there are empty strings existing in these columns, which leads to their data being incorrectly assigned as 'object'. How do  I remove those empty strings and covert the column to the correct data type (int/float)?
Suppose column A looks like this:
2
1
0
''
NULL
Name: A, dtype: object

Expected column A should be
2
1
0
NULL
NULL 
Name: A, dtype: int

I tried the below but it seems the data type is not changed, potentially all numbers are still considered as strings.
print(df[col].dtypes)
df[col].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df[col].dtypes)

Output:
object
object

I don't want to use str.isnumeric() to covert data type first because it will impact other real string columns. Is there a better approach?

It might be better/easier to fix the problem at its source. How are you loading the data? For example, if you're using pd.read_csv(), null strings should automatically get converted to NaN.

Yes. The purpose of this script is to fix the problem at its source which is Snowflake. I am using Python to develop the SQL queries that can be applied on Snowflake. It's harder to handle large amount of attributes on Snowflake, in an iterative way.

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a database with messy data that you're trying to fix using Python? OK, then e-motta's answer should fit your needs.

Yes, adding the try/except block would do the trick.

I'm assuming the columns that have numeric data only have empty strings (""or " ") along with the numbers, since you're trying to .replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan...).
If this is the case, you can call pandas.to_numeric and it will convert all numbers to numeric type, and the empty strings to nan.
Empty strings will not raise an error, but other strings will.
To handle other columns that contain other strings (not numerical), you can use a try...except:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"number_col": [1, ""], "string_col": ["some string", "other string"]}
)

  number_col    string_col
0          1   some string
1             other string

for col in df.columns:
    try:
        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])
    except ValueError:
        continue

   number_col    string_col
0         1.0   some string
1         NaN  other string


Thank you! I made some improvements based on my use case. 1. I added another condition of number of unique values >= 20, to avoid converting categories encoded as numbers to real numbers. (They should remain as strings.) 2. For the exception, I used except: (ValueError, TypeError) as e: continue.

You can use pandas.to_numeric(…, errors='coerce') to convert strings to numeric dtypes. If an uncoercable value is encountered then the result will be NaN.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> s = pd.Series([2, 1, 0, '', pd.NA], dtype='string')
>>> coerced = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
>>> coerced
0     2.0
1     1.0
2     0.0
3    <NA>
4    <NA>
dtype: Float64
>>> pd.DataFrame({'orig': s, 'new': coerced}))
   orig   new
0     2   2.0
1     1   1.0
2     0   0.0
3        <NA>
4  <NA>  <NA>


Thanks. But my df also have columns with real strings. If I do this with errors='coerce', will it just convert legitimate strings to NULLs? That is something I don't want it to happen.

Maybe I can try using 'ignore' and let it keep the original input if it is a string? Then string numbers will be converted to real numbers, but '' will be kept. Then I can replace '' as NULL. Will this make the dtype of the whole column changed to a number type?

@szheng Why would you use it on columns that contain actual string data? Just pick the columns you want to convert (the ones that contain numeric data) and apply it to them only.

@szheng "Will this make the dtype of the whole column changed to a number type?" - No, the dtype is an attribute of the column itself, not its values, and an object column can contain any value.

@wjandrea How do I know which column has the numeric data, without looking at the actual data in them? There are large number of attributes.

@szheng Oh, you have a deeper problem then. I'll add a comment on the question.
